# How can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In what way should I improve my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498723/euler-lagrange-equation-with-lagrange-multipliers) to get an answer?

Since this is a pretty "classical" example, I assume that many people have seen it and can say something about it. So there must be a problem with how I described my problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes answers to more technical problems take a while. I, for one, don’t know half of what’s necessary to answer your question. If after a while, you still get nothing, you could always try putting a bounty.

Comment: we aren't all mathematicians...